# Webpage not able to read CSS file

Tags: php, html, css, web

Hello my Code here is very simple. For some reason it is not picking up anything from the CSS file and adding it to the php file in the body section. If I make changes for the p tag in CSS it does not display the changes when I use P in php and go into the website here is my code.

**PHP CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- Created by: Sivaram Penumarty [skpenuma] -->
<?php
        include("style.css");
?>
<head>

<title>WireLess Networking Group US PDE</title>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Ye Olde Storye</h3>
<p><span>A</span> long time ago there was an intrepid young student who wanted to learn CSS...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**STYLE.CSS**

```
p {
    font-family:Garamond;
    font-size:16px;
}

h3 {
    font-family:cursive;
    color:#36648b;
    text-align:center;
}

span {
    color:#cc0000;
    font-size:24px;
}
```

This is the output onto the webpage after I try running it.

p { font-family:Garamond; font-size:16px; } h3 { font-family: cursive; color: blue; text-align: center; } span { color:green; font-size:24px; } 
Ye Olde Storye
A long time ago there was an intrepid young student who wanted to learn CSS...

As you can see the text is not aligned to the center for Ye Olde Storye and the span doesn't work for A as well as nothing for the p tag changes either. Also it reprints all the code from the style.css file in the beginning. Why is this happening?

Comment: you **dont** use php's include to link to a css file, try some documentation

Comment: add <style> tags at the beginning and the end of your style.css file

Comment: @Mooseman they put that question on hold and nobody can answer it. I flagged it also. I restructured the question a lot with lots more details so that you guys can answer it better since my question previously was not stated very clearly. Thank you.

Comment: @Dagon I am very new to this what documentation do you exactly mean.

Comment: @Akam So <style> in the beginning and </style> at the end? I have never had to use that before or even heard about that before.

Comment: yes, try also to read more about how to include external css file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just want to do this instead of the include

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- Created by: Sivaram Penumarty [skpenuma] -->

<head>

<title>WireLess Networking Group US PDE</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Ye Olde Storye</h3>
<p><span>A</span> long time ago there was an intrepid young student who wanted to learn CSS...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried that as well. It has not worked.

Comment: Depending on where your page is and the location of they style.css you will have to change the href attribute

Comment: So my index.php is in the same folder as the style.css. Do I have to put part of the pwd into the href?

Comment: the drop the leading / in the href... I will change answer to reflect this.

Comment: is this posted somewhere you can provide a link to it?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 with that link...maybe not accessible from the outside world?

Comment: that could be a reason why not. It might be that only people on our network can view the page. I did add the pwd all the way to the style.css in the href line. I really don't get why it wouldn't print if linking CSS to a php file is the same as it is to a html file.

Comment: Do you think the style.css file has to have more than just read permissions?

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT! The href needed to be the link to the webpage I guess not necessarily the pwd. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a PHP include to dump the CSS file as text into the HTML document … where it will be treated as HTML.

If you really want to include it that way, then you need to put it inside a `<style>` element.

That method, however, means that the CSS will have to be downloaded every time the HTML document is downloaded (and can't be reused between pages).

Tell the browser to load the CSS instead:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Comment: I did it your way and it still gives me same output.

Comment: That is *instead of* the PHP include, not as well as it. (If you have removed the include then you are either looking at a cached version or made an error when saving or uploading the script).

Comment: I took out the include and added your line with the pwd of the file into href and it took out printing the style.css code onto the webpage, but it does not add the CSS features to my text on the webpage.

Comment: You added the working directory? You need to give a URL (preferably a relative one). The browser doesn't know about the file system of the computer the web server runs on (and it would be a horrific security problem if it did).

Comment: Yeah I was able to figure it out. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a `<style>` container around your css file, because css is no html!

```
<style type="text/css">
  <?php
    include("style.css");
  ?>
</style>
```

As others proposed: Include the external file using the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

First open notepad, put all your html code in it, then save it as index.html(don't forget the .html extension)

Then make a new notepad file and add all your css to to it. and save it as style.css, make sure they are in same directory.

and Finally, add this code anywhere in your html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

Comment: I have done it this way and it still gives the same output as I put in the question.

Comment: can you paste your markup(html and css) in jsfiddle so i can take a look at it?

Comment: I was able to figure it out. The href was the website url to the that file. I think it has something to do with my network but that worked for me. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PHP to *just* load the stylesheet. If `style.css` is in the same directory, you could use the following line of code to reference the stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

If

`include()` just fetches the CSS file and dumps the whole code in your document. So, if you want that instead, you could do something like this:

```
<head>
    <style>
        <?php include("style.css"); ?>
    </style>
<head>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315772/how-to-import-include-a-css-file-using-php-code-and-not-html-code) and see if it helps.

Of taken from that page by [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793940/stefan):

```
<?php
define('CSSPATH', 'template/css/'); //define css path

$cssItem = 'style.css'; //css item to display

?>

<html>
<head>
 <title>Including css</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo (CSSPATH . "$cssItem"); ?>" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
...
...
</body>
</html>
```