# My css works on my local xampp server and not on my website

Tags: php, html, css

I have a [website](http://chrismunroe.pw). My css is not being applied to it. These files are exactly the same as the ones I have locally. These work on my own localhost. I use php in my css document so the file extension is .php

(my css document) main.php:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: utf-8");
?>
```

my index document calling in main.php:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Chris Munroe</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/normalize.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/main.php">

</head>
```

If you click to my about page there is another css document specifically for that page. On the website, you will see, that it works fine. What is wrong here? Can you not mingle php with css? Does it matter where I use that header in my php/css document?

Comment: Why are you defining your css file as a php?

Comment: You should quote your divs `<div id = back0>` to `<div id = "back0">` etc. etc. etc. and not use `.php` as a stylesheet.

Comment: If you want to include your css as a php you may want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315772/how-to-import-include-a-css-file-using-php-code-and-not-html-code

Comment: I'm using php in the css. Is this not something that should be done?

Comment: It's ok, check the link in my previous comment, i think it could be helpful.

Comment: FireBug knows all: **The stylesheet http://chrismunroe.pw/css/main.php was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".**

Comment: @Dagon thats an answer

Comment: no the answer is making it `text/css` when he has already set that  using header(). i suspect something in apache is taking precedence over his in file setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. It was because the utf was lower case. That was it.

fix:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
```

You can check the website for yourself its all good now....

Comment: You can accept your own answer, just cant vote it :)

Comment: should be *Content-Type* just to be carefull

Comment: @skv you can only accept your own answer 2 days after the question has been opened

Answer (score 1):

As Dagon pointed even though you are setting the content type you need to do this to enforce it.
Place the CSS in a separate folder and then

Create a `*.htaccess` file in that folder and add the following:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css
```

This should do the trick for you

Comment: Just so that I know what I said was a valid solution, any reasons for downvote? (though it does not apply to the OP)

Comment: No. You shouldn't add this handler (this is a really bad practice), as you'll turn all CSS in that folder to treat as PHP. Specify PHP header is already enough.

Comment: @Raptor that is the reason I mention the separate folder, and if this htaccess is inside a folder would it really be a bad practice?

Comment: Yes, still a bad practice. All CSS should be put in a centralized folder.

Comment: Any reasons for your statement? or a link where it is explained as bad?