# How to embed css to HTML in laravel?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-4, html-email

First of all, to make things clear, I know I can include my css file by

```
{{ HTML::style('css/myStyle.css') }}
```

Which the html to be generated will be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://myhost/public/css/myStyle.css">
```

The problem is that my view file is used for email and many email client don't load external css file. So I need to make it something like:

```
<style>
    .content-of-my-css {
        //content of my css
    }
    // more css
</style>
```

As the css settings will be used for multiple email template, I don't want to hard code it. In pure PHP, this can be done by ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6315844/1273587))

```
<style><?php include "path/to/my/css";?></style>
```

However, when I do that with laravel, it says:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) include(): http:// wrapper is disabled
>   in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

So, is there a way I can embed the css in laravel? (I am using laravel 4.2)

Comment: This helped me and could help others that find here from google https://codingwithstef.com/2021-02-11-how-to-embed-essential-styles-with-a-custom-blade-directive

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that you are using a URL instead of the local file path.

For example

```
include('http://example.com/css/styles.css');
```

will produce your error but the following should not

```
include(public_path().'css/styles.css');
```

Comment: Just for the record. You are missing a "/" -> include(public_path().'/css/styles.css'); But +1 for the answer. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using multiple template i will suggest you to create multiple style views which contain just css and you can include them with blade @include

```
style1.blade.php
style2.blade.php
```

in styles just put css code

```
<style>
    .content-of-my-css {
        //content of my css
    }
    // more css
</style>
```

in master.blade.php layout

```
<html>
  <head>@include('style1')</head>
</html>
```

if it is dynamic you can pass style parameter

```
@include($style)
```

Comment: As the css style will as well be used in email preview (which is normal web page) , so in my situation it is better to be kept as css file.

Comment: Also, it is <head> instead of <header> in html.