# I can't link my External CSS file to the other files with input type in the same folder

Tags: php, html, css, external

I am a newbie programmer and I need help in linking my External CSS with the other files.
I've been reading all question asked here about anything related to External CSS and I still can't find my answer

1. I already put the **style.css** file in the same folder as the other files that I want to link to (without sub-folder)
2. I already use the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>` by typing and not copying the code from the web
3. In my problem here, I was trying to use the External CSS for my `<textarea>` and my `<input type="text>"`
4. Does it have anything to do with me using localhost? or because i'm saving the file name as **.php?**

I think I tried everything but it still doesn't work. Did I miss something? You guidance is really appreciated. Thank you.

---

The simplified version of my codes looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
     <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="style.css"/>
     </head>

     <body>
         <input name="project"  type="text" id="project"/>
     </body>
 </html>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="text"]
{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing; border-box;
}
```

Comment: are you missing `/>` in your `link` tag?

Comment: hi.. In my code up there I accidentally forgot to close the `link` tag. It was there on my real file. Btw, can I edit my own question? this is my first time using stackoverflow so I don't really know my way around here.

Comment: @Danielle Yes you can edit your question and make changes.

Comment: @LavyaR thank you... :)

Comment: @ChavaG  
oh no.. it was there in my real file. I must miss that when i'm typing the code manually just now in this question.... thank you for noticing that :), i just edit that question.

Comment: what happens if you replace `input[type="text"]` with `#project` ??

Comment: @KavishMittal it still doesn't work. btw thank you for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in [How to import/include a CSS file using PHP code and not HTML code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315772/how-to-import-include-a-css-file-using-php-code-and-not-html-code)

Since I'm saving the file as **.php,** I tried using

```
<style>
<?php include('style.css');?>
</style>
```

and it works. Thanks everyone.. :)

Comment: that should not be the answer though. As pure html in php file should work fine ..you dont necessarily need to have any PHP tag in a .php file
Your html code was also fine as such

Comment: Check if your style.css is actually **style.css** or its **style.css.txt** in reality.
You will need to unhide extension of files in your computer to be able to see this

Comment: @KavishMittal I did used the regular code using the `link` but it still doesn't work out. I don't know why... and i checked the file extension it is style.css and not style.css.txt. i also try coding again from the scratch but it also return the same result in my browser. Does it have anything to do with using localhost?


btw, thank you for your opinion... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried code of yours and its working finer no need to dace your file as .php

```
<html>
         <head>
             <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="style.css"/>
         </head>

         <body>
             <input name="project" type="text" id="project"/>
         </body>
</html>
```

and css

```
input[type="text"]
{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing; border-box;
    background: red;
}
```

I have apply `background: red;` to verify and its working properly