# How to hard code first headline of article red

Tags: css, wordpress

I would like to color a heading of a post red. The whole thing I want to do with CSS and the ID of the post. How should I proceed, assuming the ID is 84?

So the real problem is that I don't know how to address the ID via CSS and color the heading red.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
                            <?php while (have_posts()) : ?>
                                <?php the_post(); ?>
                                    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                                        <section class="info box">
                                            <p>
                                                Geschrieben von <b><?php the_author(); ?></b> am <?php the_time('j. F Y'); ?> um <?php the_time('G:i'); ?> Uhr,
                                                abgelegt unter <?php the_category(' | '); ?>
                                            </p>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanenter Link zu diesem Artikel">
                                                <?php the_title('<h2>', '</h2>', true); ?>
                                            </a>
                                            <div>
                                                <?php comments_popup_link('Kein Kommentar', '1 Kommentar', '% Kommentare', '', 'Kommentare sind abgeschaltet.'); ?>
                                                <?php edit_post_link('Bearbeiten',' | ',''); ?>                                                    
                                            </div>
                                            <?php the_content('<br /><span>Weiterlesen</span>'); ?>
                                        </section>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if (is_page()) : ?>
                                        <?php comments_template(); ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <p>                                    
                                <?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link') ?>
                                <?php next_post_link('<span style="float:right">%link &raquo;</span>') ?>
                            </p>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <h2>Nichts gefunden</h2>
                            <p>Sorry, aber du suchst gerade nach etwas, was hier nicht ist.</p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You address the id with # and classes with a dot. So in your case #84 { color: red; }

Comment: @Dino How does the CSS file then know that the ID is meant by the post and not any 84?

Comment: Did you try that, Dino? Unless things have changed, that’s unlikely to work as written.

Comment: @Dino Please read and study before giving that kind of wrong advice: https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: if the post id is `84`, in your case, you just do: `#post-84{ color: #red; }`

Comment: @cornel.raiu color: red; not #red

Comment: whatever :)) you get the point: `#post-84{ color: red; }` or `#post-84{ color: #f40000; }` It's late here. I mixed the 2 versions :)

Comment: thanks @ManuelQuintanilla it goes ahead. the problem now is that everything in the post is red except the heading. and i want it to be exactly the other way round :D

Comment: @sharete I updated completely - should work

Comment: @sharete I think it would be better if you posted a sample of the produced HTML as it would be presented in the browser instead of the server side code. After all, that would be the HTML that your CSS would apply to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on post ID 84 you can try the following:

```css
#post-84 h2 {
color:red;
}
```

Comment: `#84` is NOT a valid CSS selector  https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: `#eighty-four` will never be a standard WP post selector. What you are looking for is `#post-84`

Comment: NOOOO :)) that will make each post title red. because the file the OP got the code for the questions is a single post file, most probably single.php or similar. That means, each page will get the selector with the current post id. that means ALL the posts will have the title red when you visit them.

Comment: RIP this post @cornel.raiu I updated my post hahaha

Comment: haha. It is funny because the OP does not seem to know what is the actual need. So we just keep guessing :)

Answer (score 0):

When using ids and classes know that ids should only be used once, while classes can be used on multiple elements. It's best to use a string instead of an integer to set an id name as it will not always work with an integer.

```html
<ul>
  <li id="red-text">First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>

<style>
  #red-text {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: i would like to use your method, unfortunately i have no idea where to insert it in my code. i have edited my post, can you help me there again? thank you

Comment: @sharete you have to do it in your `style.css` file or any other file that loads in that page ( never touch plugin or theme core files. Only do changes in your plugins or the child theme )

Comment: @sharete or you can do it in the Appearance -> Customize area where you have the custom CSS field ( in case your theme supports it )

Comment: @cornel.raiu i put the part into the css, as you said, unfortunately nothing happens. i also don't understand where the index.php from the stylesheet gets the info from, that post-84 means post with id 84?

Comment: @sharete what index.php??? From the code you posted `id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"` this will generate `id="post-84"` for the post id 84. So, if you add `#post-84{ color: red; }` to your style.css file, it will all work. But only for the post with the id=84

Comment: @sharete can you provide a link to the page where you need that to happen? Do you have a post with the id=84? :)

Comment: hi @sharete, sorry I didn't see this sooner. as cornel.raiu mentioned, the css will be in your style.css file while the actual tags will be in index.php. In your index.php you will have to reference the style.css file. Take a look at this post for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315772/how-to-import-include-a-css-file-using-php-code-and-not-html-code)