# Absolute paths with or without domain?

Tags: html

I have many HTML pages, like so:

```
...
http://www.mydomain/app/library/index.php
http://www.mydomain/app/library/admin/admin.php
...
```

I use an external file to include the `<head>` in my html, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es_ES"><?php

include("path/to/html/head/head.php"); ?>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

the `head.php` looks like

```
<head>
...
<link href="" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Let's say i want to link the css file in `head.php`. Should i use absolute path with domain for links, like so

```
<head>
...
<link href="http://www.mydomain/app/library/common/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

or, should i use absolute path without domain, like so:

```
<head>
...
<link href="/app/library/common/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

I don't think i can use relative paths (or maybe i should... i don't know).

Personally, i like the absolute path without domain... But i want to make sure it's done correctly the first time.

Are there any pros/cons on using absolute paths with or without domain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import/include a CSS file using PHP code and not HTML code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315772/how-to-import-include-a-css-file-using-php-code-and-not-html-code)

Comment: Links in the HTML generated have nothing to do with how you load your PHP files. The browser interprets the HTML, not PHP.

Answer (score -1):

You have to give full path with domain like this.

```
<head>
...
<link href="http://www.mydomain/app/library/common/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

If you give path as below,

```
<head>
...
<link href="/app/library/common/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

then it will find in the local, so you have to give with domain.

Comment: both work, my question is about the pros/cons on using absolute paths with or without domain