# how to link bootstrap file in directory html files using php

Tags: php, html

I have a header file which includes links to Bootstrap and jQuery. I include this header in both my *index* file and my *FAQ* file. The links in the index file work fine, but the Bootstrap link in the FAQ file does not work.

**My header file:**

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".././style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".././../jQuery/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src=".././../jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src=".././../jQuery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Here's my Index file, where I include the header:**

```
<?php
$title = "Home page";                   // (1) Set the title
include "header.php";                 // (2) Include the header
?>
```

**And here's my FAQ file, where I also include the header:**

```
<?php
$title = "Home page";                   // (1) Set the title
include "../header.php";                 // (2) Include the header
?>
```

Here are snapshots of my directories:

[Root directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9jo7.png)
[Front directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oqdS.png)

Comment: This question has been asked many times here is one of them : https://stackoverflow.com/q/6315772/12232340

Answer (score 0):

I think that is bucause your relative path for example this:

```
.././../jQuery/jquery-ui.js
```

You shoud change them to the absolute path and it solve your problem
For example change to sth like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo __DIR__ ?>/../../jQuery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **.env** file. [Dotenv package](https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/phpdotenv) You can set your links to files in it and then use $_ENV global variable. Just try to use Dotenv extension.